# Build .deb Packages With PHP

Tags: php, bash, debian, bzip2

I have a website that needs to build a debian package and move it into a different directory for people to download. I have been able to do this using Linux and bash files to compress and build a Packages file with dpkg. Here's the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter app name
read NAME
cd /home/stumpx/cydia/apps
dpkg -b $NAME
cp /home/stumpx/cydia/apps/$NAME.deb /home/stumpx/cydia/upload/deb/$NAME.deb
cd /home/stumpx/cydia/upload
dpkg-scanpackages -m . /dev/null >Packages
bzip2 /home/stumpx/cydia/upload/Packages -f -k
```

It would be nice I guess to make .bz2 files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot your question. But I'll answer it regardless. Use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to invoke your bash script.

Comment: Will that command work on a host such as enom? If it does then that would make things a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: I have no clue what enom does or has.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to execute system commands. This is done via exec() in php. So you will have to write a bash script that does it all ( build package, compress and move it ) and execute it using php